# Determining the popularity of a video with ratings and views

Tags: math, statistics, voting, rating-system

I am about to embark on a new project - a video website. Users will be able to register, and vote on videos by clicking "like" or "dislike", or something to that effect. In any event, it will be a 2-option voting system, not a 5-star system.

Every X number of days, I will be generating a "chart" of the most popular videos. So my question is: how should I determine the popularity of a given video?

If I went the route of tallying up the videos with the most views, this could have the effect of exceptionally bad videos making it to the of the charts (just because they're so bad).

If I go the route of a scoring system based on the amount of "like" and "dislike" votes (eg. 100 like votes, and 50 dislike votes equals a score of 2), videos with few views could appear on the top of the charts.

So, what I need to do is a combination of the two. Barring, of course, spammy views and votes.

What's your guys' thoughts on the subject?

**Edit**: *the following tags were removed: [**mysql**] [**postgresql**], to make room for other, more representative tags;  the SQL technology used in the intended implementation does not seem to bear much on the considerations regarding the rating model per-se.*

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be missing the point that **likes and dislikes in movies are anything but objective** even within the context of a relatively homogeneous group of "voters".  Think how the term "**Chix Flix**" or the success story called "***NetFlix***",  illustrate this subjectivity...

Yet, if you persist in implementing the model you suggest, there are several hidden variables and system dynamics that need to be acknowledged and possibly taken into account in the rating's formula.

- the existence of **a third, implicit, value of the vote**:  "No vote"
  i.e. when someone views the movie page and yet doesn't vote, either way.
  The problem of dealing with this extra value is its ambiguity: do people not vote because they didn't see the movie or because they neither truly like nor disliked it?  Very likely a bit of both, therefore we can/should  use the count of the "Page views without vote" in the formula, to boost (somewhat) the rating of movies that do not generate a strong (positive or negative) sentiment  (lest the "polarizing" movies will appear more notorious or popular)
- the [**bandwagon effect**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwagon_effect)
  Past a certain threshold, and particularly if the rating and/or vote counts is visible before the page view, the rating and vote counts can influence the way people decide to vote (either way) or even decide to abstain from voting.  The implication is that the total vote and/or view counts do not relate linearly to the effective rating.
- **"*quality*" vs. "*notoriety*"**
  Vote ratios in general (eg "likes" / "total" or "likes"/"dislikes" etc.) are indicative of the "quality" of a movie (note the quotes around quality...), whereby the number of votes (and of views) is indicative of the notoriety ("name recognition" etc.) of a movie.
- **statistical representativity**
  Very small vote and/or view counts are to be handled carefully because they introduce much volatility in the rating.  Phrased otherwise, small samples make for not so statically representative ratings.
- **trends** (the time variable)
  At the risk of complicating the model, consider keeping [some] record of when votes/view happened, to allow identifying "hot" (and "cooling") movies in the collection.  This info may inform the rating logic, but also may be used to direct the users towards currently hot items. BTW, hence feeding the bandwagon effect mentioned :-( but also, increasing the voting sample size :-).

All these considerations suggest caution in implementing this rating system.  It also hints at the likely **need of including statistics about the *complete* set of movies into the rating formula for an individual movie**.  In other words, do not rate a given movie solely on the basis of the its own vote/view counts but also on say the average vote counts a move receives, the maximum view a movie page gets etc.   In fact, an iterative process, whereby movies are [roughly] ranked at first and then the ranking is recalculated by using the statistics of groups of movies similarly rated may provide a better system (provided the formulas are "fair" and somehow converge)

Comment: Thanks for listing those design considerations, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A standard trick is to start with a neutral baseline: say 10 likes and 10 dislikes that gives a score of 1. The first few votes don't change the ratio too much, but as votes accumulate, the baseline is overwhelmed. The exact choice of the baseline values will influence the rating of a new movie (the two values don't have to be equal), and how many votes are needed to change the rating substantially.